# URL Rewriting in Varnish - Remove unwanted URL parameters

Tags: regex, url-rewriting, varnish

My application is generating pages based off of 4 unique URL parameters and I'm trying to get varnish to cache the page. This scenario is a bit unusual as I have no control over the amount or the order of the URL parameters being passed to my application. With my limited regex skill set and googling abilities, I've found a solution to match the parameters that I want:

```
[&|?](?:Param1|Param2|Param3|Param4)=[^&\s]+
```

But due to the limitations of VCL, I need the exact opposite:

```
Match any URL parameters that are not Param1, Param2, Param3 or Param4.
```

Then remove from URL, set hash_data based off url, forward to my backend and I should be golden.

I'm hoping someone with some regex experience can share a solution or point me in the right direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want [negative lookahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), which you use with `(?!...)`. I don't know what your parameters look like so I guessed with `[\w\d]+`.

```
[&|?](?!Param1|Param2|Param3|Param4)[\w\d]+=[^&\s]+
```

Comment: I tried something very similar to this before posting but I didn't include the [\w\d]+ after the parameter's group. After getting some sleep and clearing my head, it makes perfect sense and works perfectly in varnish. Thanks!